# Python - how to fix the unhashable type: 'dict' and format requires a mapping for operator tripple quotes

Tags: python

How do i get the arr and myname formatted?

```
arr = { 
'pincode':'pincode',
'username':'username',
'password':'password',
'action':'action',
'forward':'forward'
}
myname="myname"
print """my pincode is: %(pincode)s and my name is: %s !""" % {arr, myname}
print """my pincode is: %(pincode)s and my name is: %s !""" % (arr, myname)
```

expecting output:

my pincode is: pincode and my name is: myname !

getting:

```
TypeError: format requires a mapping

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: Can't you just add `myname` as another entry in the dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
arr = { 
'pincode':'pincode',
'username':'username',
'password':'password',
'action':'action',
'forward':'forward'
}
myname="myname"
print """my pincode is: %s and my name is: %s !""" % (arr['pincode'], myname)
```

You can also use named arguments with [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
print 'my pincode is: {pincode} and my name is: {myname} !'.format(
       myname=myname, **arr)
```

Note setting the keyword `myname` to its value prior to setting all the other keywords in the mapping by using `**arr`.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the new [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
arr = { 
'pincode':'PINCODE',
'username':'USERNAME',
'password':'PASSWORD',
'action':'ACTION',
'forward':'FORWARD'
}
myname="MYNAME"
print """my pincode is: {pincode} and my name is: {0}!""".format(myname, **arr)
```

for example:

```
>>> arr = {
... 'pincode':'PINCODE',
... 'username':'USERNAME',
... 'password':'PASSWORD',
... 'action':'ACTION',
... 'forward':'FORWARD'
... }
>>> myname="MYNAME"
>>> print """my pincode is: {pincode} and my name is: {0}!""".format(myname, **arr)
my pincode is: PINCODE and my name is: MYNAME!
>>>
```

the `**arr` should pass the dictionary as keywords to `format`.

Comment: I normally hate when people answer questions on SO with "your problem is you should actually be using this other thing instead", but in this case new-style formatting really is so much better than old style.  This should be the only answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = {
'pincode':'pincode',
'username':'username',
'password':'password',
'action':'action',
'forward':'forward'
}
myname="myname"
print """my pincode is: %s and my name is: %s !""" % (arr['pincode'], myname)
print """my pincode is: %s and my name is: %s !""" % (arr['pincode'], myname)
```

This seems to work

EDIT: Ah, was beaten to it!